# Is ADO unable to report a database is marked read-only?

Tags: delphi, ado

If "read only" is checked in the Windows desktop properties for a .dbf or .mdb file, 
and a Delphi 6 ADO connection (say, via Jet for an .mdb file or ODBC for a .dbf file) 
is then used to open that database, TADOTable.CanModify returns true and 
TADOTable.ReadOnly returns false, apparently failing to detect the file is 
actually read-only.

From the VCL source, it looks like .CanModify is just set from Supports(xUpdates) 
and .ReadOnly is set from the LockType (even "read-only data source" in 
TADOConnection.Properties returns 0), so those properties seem more like 
tools for detecting connectionstring options as opposed to detecting the 
database's original read-only state.

So what's the proper ADO technique to detect a database is marked read-only 
*before* TADOTable.Edit is attempted?  Seems the solution should *not* be 
specific to Windows files, but some kind of database-independent technique 
using just ADO.  What's the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a pity, but you can't.

However, since the filename is part of the connection string, you can check yourself.

Comment: for a .txt or .dbf file, the connection string might name only the "database" (the parent folder) and the file is the table (possibly independently marked read-only). hence, you have to check at both levels (the file named in the connection string for some databases, or the table itself for other kinds of databases).

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is old, but it seems the accepted answer is at least incomplete. From my own experiments it seems you *can* detect a read-only database prior to attempting to edit data:

My setup:

I create a TADOConnection to a MDB file using the following ConnectionString: `Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="C:\SomePath\MyDatabase.mdb";` I use a few more flags but they don't seem to matter here.

Normally when connecting, `MyADOConnection.Mode` switches from `cmUnknown` to `cmShareDenyNone`.

My observation:

When `C:\SomePath\MyDatabase.mdb` file is marked as read-only by the operating system, the connection's `Mode` property switches to `cmRead` instead upon connecting.

I can access this property directly from my `TADODataset` through `MyDataset.Connection.Mode`

Side note: In my experiments, subsequent connections required `Mode` to be reset to `cmUnknown` in order for it to be able to switch back properly to `cmShareDenyNone`.

Please also note that editing a row may still fail for various other reasons, even if `Mode` returns `cmShareDenyNone`. This does, however solve the original question, as to how to detect a MDB that is marked as "read-only" by the OS.